# Matrices Anidadas Array

Tags: python

Para empezar necesito un input el cual tendrá unas condiciones de entrada: ser entero y estar entre 0 y 100.
Cualquier otro tipo de valor (todos los posibles), regresará una alerta de que el valor es incorrecto:

```
import re
N = input("Introduzca un Numero entero entre [ 0 y 100 ] ")
a = re.compile(r'^\+?[1-9][0-9]*$')
it_si = re.match(a,N)
if it_si:

    print(f'El valor introducido es :{N} ')
else: print(f'El termino: {N}... no es un Numero Entero entre 0 y 100')
```

Una vez que tenemos esto:
Quiero generar una Matriz la cual contenga en el centro de la misma el número 1, a continuación le rodeará el número 2 que a su vez repetirá el 3... Hasta N, el valor que introducimos antes.
[image: Ejemplo]

De esta manera recitaría ayuda para generar la matriz correcta puesto que lo he conseguido solo es generar ceros.

```
numero = int(input("Introducir numero Intento numero 5000 xD: ")) 

matrix = [] 
  
for i in range(numero):          
    a =[] 
    for j in range(numero): 

        a.append(int()) 
    matrix.append(a) 
  
for i in range(numero): 
    for j in range(numero): 
        print(matrix[i][j], end = " ") 
    print()
```

Comment: Terminando de editar tu pregunta, me pregunto: _¿cuál es el problema / la pregunta?_

Comment: el problema es que cuando lo ejecutamos... Tendría que salir una secuencia similar a la captura pero en lugar de ello me salen ceros llenado la matriz.

Comment: `int()` produce un 0, por tanto estás rellenando con ceros. ¿por qué esperabas que fuese a salir el patrón deseado? tienes que inicializar cada elemento con un valor que dependa de `i` y `j` según el patrón deseado.

Comment: entonces valdría con decir que para i = N*2-1 y j=N*2-1, por que esa seria la lógica para que pinte la matriz?

Comment: No te entiendo, pero no tienes más que probarlo y ver si funciona :-) Por otro lado, el título de la pregunta habla de numpy pero tu código no lo usa. Creo que usándolo (y sus _slices_) se simplificaría mucho el problema. Tampoco veo por qué has puesto la etiqueta python-2.7 ya que este código no usa esa versión. Mejor quitas esa etiqueta.

Comment: El problema original era desarrollar una matriz donde los únicos parámetros de entrada fueran números enteros de entre 0 y 100 (cualquier otro parámetro de entrada debería regresar aviso al usuario de que no es numero). Una vez que tenemos eso lo que se nos pide es desarrollar una matriz la cual la rellenaremos tanto filas como columnas de tal forma que sigamos la lógica de N-2-1. Entonces si el usuario pone un 5... La primera capa de la matriz la rellena con 5 la anterior con 4... así sucesivamente hasta llegar a uno.

Answer (score 0):

Ya que se trata de una tarea de algún curso, y este sitio no resuelve tareas a los usuarios, me limitaré a darte algunas ideas para que tú mismo llegues a la solución.

### Creación de la matriz

Lo primero ¿de qué tamaño es la matriz que debes crear? Si observas su estructura, verás que siempre tiene un número impar de filas (y de columnas, pues la matriz es cuadrada), y que ese número es fácil de calcular dado N. Las N primeras filas tienen los números de N a 1 descendente, y las N-1 siguientes tienen de 2 a N de nuevo. Así que el total es N + N -1, o sea 2N-1

Por tanto debes comenzar por crear una matriz de tamaño (2N-1)x(2N-1) rellena con el número N. Esto es fácil con numpy. No necesitas ningún tipo de bucles ni listas ni appends. La función `np.zeros()` te retorna una matriz rellena con ceros, del tamaño que le indiques:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(shape=(2*N-1, 2*N-1))
```

Ahora, gracias a que numpy opera "vectorialmente" (sobre varios elementos de una matriz a la vez) basta hacer `a = a + N` en una sola instrucción para que todos los ceros de `a` pasen a tener el valor `N` (pues se suma N a todos ellos).

### Estructura solicitada

Tenemos una matriz rellena de números iguales (`N`) pero queremos que dentro de ella haya otra mas pequeña rellena de N-1, y dentro de esa otra más pequeña aún rellena de N-2, así hasta llegar a una matriz de un solo elemento en el centro, que contenga el valor 1.

numpy permite seleccionar un sub-rango de una matriz con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
a[fila_inicial:fila_final, columna_inicial:columna_final]
```

Recuerda que además los índices en python pueden ser negativos, lo que cuenta desde el final. Esto hace sencillo seleccionar una submatriz que excluya las primeras y últimas filas y columnas, que es lo que necesitas. Además se puede asignar un valor al sub-rango seleccionado en una sola asignación, por ejemplo:

```
a[1:-1, 1:-1] = N-1
```

Esta expresión seleccionará la submatriz que va de la fila 1 a la -1, y lo mismo con las columnas. Es decir, la submatriz que resulta de excluir la fila 0 y la última fila, y lo mismo con las columnas. A esa submatriz (a todos sus elementos en una sola instrucción) les asignamos el valor N-1.

Estos son los rudimentos. Ahora sólo te queda pensar cómo hacer el bucle que repita la operación anterior para cada una de las submatrices necesarias.

Comment: Muchas Gracias por las directrices intentare haber si lo consigo. Si es para una tarea pero no hay manera xD. Si lo consigo lo publicare por aquí. Muy amable por todo...